# Add to MS-SQL table from C# Winform datagridview

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms

I have a application that is supposed to add rows of data from a datagridview to a SQL-table. I have a working solution now, but it is quite slow because it uses a foreach loop to add data to the table. See code:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridViewName.Rows)
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        String sqlRaw = "INSERT INTO tblTable(" +
            "Column1, Column2, Column3)" +
            "SELECT " +
            "Column1Value, Column2Value, Column3Value" +
            "FROM [tblOtherTable] " +
            "WHERE [Criteria1] = '{0}'";

            cmd.CommandText = String.Format(sqlRaw, row.Cells[0].Value);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

(I have modified the example code so its easier to read).

Is there a faster way to add data to an sql-table or do I have to do it one row at a time?

Edit, I have updated the code to show that the criteria uses information from each row to insert into the sql table.

Comment: Can't see how the query depends on the `dataGridViewName` data but the number of rows.

Comment: You should *never* construct SQL by concatenating strings and input like this. That's how SQL injection attacks happen. What if the input contains `'); DROP TABLE tblTable;--` ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, thank you for the input, even if it was not what I asked for in the first place. Could you point me in the right direction for how to do it correctly?

Comment: Don't try to save the GUI element, save the DataTable that's bound to it. ADO.NET tutorials show how to bind DataGridView to a DataTable through the DataSource property and how to save any changes to the Datatable using table adapters. Check [How to: Bind data to the Windows Forms DataGridView control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-bind-data-to-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

Comment: For SQL queries in general, use parameterized queries instead of concatenating or formatting strings. It's actually easier to write a parameterized query than getting string concatenation right. [This doc examples shows how to do this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/configuring-parameters-and-parameter-data-types#example) but you can get rid of all the boilerplate using eg [Dapper](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper) to reduce all the code to a single line `var dog = connection.Query<Dog>("select Age = @Age, Id = @Id", new { Age = (int?)null, Id = guid });`

Comment: In parameterized queries, the values are passed as strongly-typed binary values to the server outside the query itself, as parameters in the RPC call to the server. The server constructs an execution plan from that query that accepts parameters and executes it using the supplied values. The values are never converted to string and never combined with the query string itself. This prevents SQL injection *and* avoids date and decimal conversion problems

Answer (score 0):

All of the tips regarding SQL injection are important to listen to; however, you don't necessarily need to worry about it if the queries are not something user manipulated data will be entered into.

If you aren't concerned with SQL injection, then instead of creating an individual `SqlCommand` for each row, you could instead concatenate all of your rows into a single string SQL [transaction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/begin-transaction-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) and commit it all at once and see how well that performs compared to your current method. Note that if any part of the transaction fails, the whole thing will roll back, and you'll have to re-run all of the queries that it contained.